# Recursive regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am practicing regex with C#. This is my code:

```
string test =
    "this is whole new line, with different parameters 10.1.2.1, 10.1.5.1, 10.1.3.1";
string a = Regex.Match(test, "10.[0-9].[0-9]+.[0-9]+").Value;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The result is *10.1.2.1*. It finds the first match and that's it.

How can I perform this function recursively ? Do I need to add some extra code or is there a regex class which has this as a built in function (which I would prefer)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are explicitly asking for only one match, using the `Match` method. You should use `Matches` instead, and iterate over the result:

```
string test = "this is whole new line, with different parameters 10.1.2.1, 10.1.5.1, 10.1.3.1";
foreach(Match result in Regex.Matches(test, "10.[0-9].[0-9]+.[0-9]+"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);  
}
```

That code will print the following:

```
10.1.2.1
10.1.5.1
10.1.3.1
```

Comment: @user1068846 You can show your appreciation by accepting the answer.

Comment: sir i clicked on post is useful. Is it accepted ? i am sorry but i really clicked on it

Comment: user1068846: it is now. I think there is some sort of time limit so that you can't mark an answer as accepted until that time has passed (in order to allow for other, potentially better answers to be posted).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `RegEx.Match()`:

> Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the
>   regular expression specified in the Regex constructor.

It does exactly what it should, returns the first match. If you want all matches you should use [`RegEx.Matches(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx).

Comment: Sir i know that :-), i m asking is there anyway i can get all the occurrences with some regex builtin function ?